# Put an object inside google map fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I'm working with google maps API for Android.
The map is within a fragment.
I want to place an image within that fragment, and above the map.
My goal is to move the photo and resize events with gestures Android.
My question is: How can I put an image over the map?

I have a method that returns me a View with the image and lets me move and resize.

How can I put this View inside the map?

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"

android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" > 

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/fotoPrueba"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="200dp"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
  />

  </LinearLayout> 
  </fragment>

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bitmap bitmap =   BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ImageTest);
    View view = new SandboxView(this, bitmap);  //returns me a View with the image and lets me move and resize.

    ImageView iv= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fotoPrueba);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

   //setContentView(view); // This works but deletes my map.

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map=    ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }
```

Comment: Don't post so ugly code without indents. You can simply reformat it in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Put your views outside map fragment in layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:orientation="vertical">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/fotoPrueba"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="200dp"
         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <!-- here can be you view -->
    <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/container"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</FrameLayout>
```